# Order by utf8_vietnamese_ci in mysql not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Sorry if my English is bad, I create a board in Vietnamese and charset = utf8_vietnamese_ci and want to arrange it in alphabet but it is not in accordance with Vietnamese standard.
For example:
input: b,ạ,á,à,a,ã,ả
The output if correct would be: a,à,ả,ã,á,ạ,b
but the real results are: a,á,à,ạ,ả,ã,b.
Is there any way for it to work properly? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the following link : it seems someone has already created another vietnamese collation. You may reuse it : http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/howto/vietcollationmysql.html

Comment: Thank you today it worked very well.